# Insert a cell with javascript and then insert checkboxes into it?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a table with javascript, and in some of the cells, put in radiobuttons and checkboxes with javascript.
I found this code:

```
function insRow() {
        var x = document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow(0);
        var y = x.insertCell(0);
        y.setAttribute('id', "NewDiv");
}
```

(the last line (`setAttribute`) is a line that I added.  I thought that I could give the new table cell an ID, and then use `document.GetElementByID` with that ID in various subroutines.  That does not work.  Now maybe making a global variable to store a copy of 'y' in would work - I could use it in the routines.  But shouldn't the above code also work?

Comment: You don't need to use `setAttribute` to set an element's ID. Just use `myElement.id = "desiredvalue"`.

Comment: No, you should not create multiple elements with the same id - that's invalid, and `getElementById` will only get the first occurence

Comment: Either I didn't understand your question or your code works. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/hW8qf/. It creates the new row and column but doesn't have anything inside. You can inspect it using chrome or use firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document.getElementById` method *(lowercase `"g"` and `"d"`)* will only work once the element is added to the DOM.

Ultimately, if possible, do your manipulations from the `y` variable, before it's appended, but it will be accessible by ID just like any other element.